# Why do I get messages from [Unassigned] and how do I remove them from my notifications?

Tags: steam

I get these empty messages from a person called [unassigned] with no steam profile and I can't seem to remove the notification from steam. Is there any way to delete these?

Comment: Accounts that are marked with [Unassigned] are stolen and used by scammers. Don't accept them.

Comment: ok thanks...i can't get rid of them from my inbox tho...

Comment: Try clicking [Mark All as Read](http://i.imgur.com/qNWCOBx.png).

Comment: tried that, but the icon on the upper right still shows up as green and the "message is still there

Comment: There is an option to stop people not on your friends list from sending you messages. I use that to stop any spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this myself before. It only cleared after completely re-installing steam. Harsh reality but atleast it keeps games stored.

Perhaps do this?

EDIT:

Please make sure Steamapps folder is backed up!

Comment: lmao this actually worked believe it or not

Comment: it's rather annoying is'nt it? I've only had it happen once and I exhausted many options and this was the only way I was able to clear it :P

Glad it helped!